# how to calculate the CPU time for query execution or Stored Procedure?

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm working on SQL SERVER 2008 R2 Performance tunning part but I'm new in it.

How to calculate:

- CPU usage time
- Logical reads
- Writes

etc. made by a query or Stored Procedure.

Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Grab [Plan Explorer](https://www.solarwinds.com/free-tools/plan-explorer) (it's free), enter your EXEC call or query, and generate an actual execution plan. You will get all kinds of interesting metrics, including CPU and I/O. In addition to a much more usable plan than you get in Management Studio.

(Disclaimer: I used to work for SQL Sentry.)

Answer (score 3):

`SET STATISTICS IO` and `SET STATISTICS TIME` are two settings that can help you measure execution of a query of stored procedure..

`SET STATISTICS IO` displays statistics on the amount of disk activity generated by the query. `SET STATISTICS TIME` displays the amount of time needed to parse, compile, and execute each statement in the query.

```
USE <Your Database>;
GO       
SET STATISTICS IO ON;
SET STATISTICS TIME ON;
GO
SELECT * 
FROM YourTable
WHERE KeyValue > 1200
GO
SET STATISTICS IO OFF;
SET STATISTICS TIME OFF;
GO
```

**Possible Result**

```
Table 'YourTable'. Scan count 1, logical reads 5, physical 
reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, 
lob read-ahead reads 0.


SQL Server parse and compile time: 
   CPU time = 0 ms, elapsed time = 1 ms.
SQL Server parse and compile time: 
   CPU time = 0 ms, elapsed time = 1 ms.

(269 row(s) affected)

SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 2 ms.
SQL Server parse and compile time: 
   CPU time = 0 ms, elapsed time = 1 ms.
```